# T-SQL Concatenating

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to concatenate the following statement in SQL.

I am joining 2 tables, the `MEDINFO` table and the `IMMUNIZE` table.

There should be one record for each of the shot code dates as long as it is not `null` or `01/01/1901`.

The output must look like this:

```
"Admin-" + medinfo_field_31 + ", Manuf-" + medinfo_field_32 + ", Lot-" + medinfo_field_33 + ", Exp-" + medinfo_field_34 + ", Site-" + medifno_field_35 + ", Dose-" + medinfo_field_36
```

Here is the criteria for the SQL statement I must create:

```
IF immunize_shot_code = 'FLU', 
   then concatenate medinfo_field_12 and medinfo_field_19 thru medinfo_field_24

IF immunize_shot_code = 'MENI', 
   then concatenate medinof_field_11 and medinfo_field_25 thru medinof_field_30

IF immunize_shot_code = 'TETA', 
   then concatenate medinfo_field_13 thru medinfo_field_18 and medinfo_field_31 thru medinfo_field_36"
```

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: look into CASE ... WHEN. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx

Comment: We're here to help, not do it for you

Comment: `Case when immunize_shot_Code = 'FLU' then concat(field32,",",field33,",",field34...) when immunize_Shot_Code = 'MENI' then concat(field11","..) when immunize_Shot_code = 'TETA' then concat(field13,",",field14,",") end`...

Answer (score 0):

This would look something like the followning:

```
SELECT 

    (CASE WHEN Immunize_shot_code='Flu'
          THEN medinfo_field_12+', '+med_info_field_19+ ', '+med_info_field_20+', '+med_info_field_21+ ', '+med_info_field_22+', '+med_info_field_23+', 'med_info_field_24
         WHEN immunize_shot_code='MENI'
           THEN [CONCATINATE AS PER ABOVE]
        .....
        .....
        END) as ImmuCode
FROM TABLE_1
```

Answer (score 0):

Like some of them mentioned above, you could use `CASE` statement something like this:

```
select 
case when i.immunize_shot_Code = 'FLU' 
        then concat(m.medinfo_field_12,',',m.medinfo_field_19,',',m.medinfo_field_24...) 
     when i.immunize_Shot_Code = 'MENI' 
        then concat(m.medinfo_field_11,',',m.medinfo_field_11) 
     when i.immunize_Shot_code = 'TETA' 
        then concat(m.medinfo_field_13,',',m.medinfo_field18,',')
 end  as concat_value
from medinfo m
join immunize i on m.id = i.medinfo_id     --change this to match your join
where (shot_code_date is not null or shot_code_date <> '01-01-1901');
```